# Did Skolem (and others) consider all "legitimate" models to be "actually" countable?

Tags: logic, set-theory, philosophy

In Thoralf Skolem's *Remarks on Axiomatized Set Theory* (van Heijenoort translation), Skolem says:

> There is no contradiction at all if a set $M$ of the domain $B$ is nondenumerable in the sense of the axiomatization; for this means merely that *within* $B$ there occurs no one-to-one mapping $\Phi$ of $M$ onto $Z_0$ (Zermelo's number sequence). Nevertheless there exists the possibility of numbering all objects in $B$, and therefore also the elements of $M$, by means of the positive integers...Thus, axiomatizing set theory leads to a relativity of set-theoretic notions, and this relativity is inseparably bound up with every thoroughgoing axiomatization...In order to obtain something absolutely nondenumerable, we would have to have either an absolutely nondenumerably infinite number of axioms or an axiom that could yield an absolutely nondenumerable number of first-order propositions. But this would in all cases lead to a circular introduction of the higher infinities; that is, ***on an axiomatic basis higher infinities exist only in a relative sense***.

And the abstract of [this paper](https://philpapers.org/rec/JANROS) on Skolem's work says:

> Skolem's critique of set theory is seen as part of a larger argument to the effect that no conclusive evidence has been given for the existence of uncountable sets. Some replies to Skolem are discussed and are shown not to affect Skolem's position, since they all presuppose the existence of uncountable sets.

All of this sounds like an assertion that no definitively "legitimate" model of set theory is ever "really" uncountable. Or to (try to) interpret it more precisely, that: For any fully "legitimate" (i.e. "guaranteed" to exist) model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZF(C)}$, when $M$ is viewed "from the outside" there is always some way of establishing a one-to-one correspondence between the sets of $M$ and the (standard) natural numbers.

- Note that I'm being intentionally vague about what exactly it means to "view $M$ from the outside" and what exactly is "some way" of establishing a one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$. Maybe this is done within some larger model of set theory, maybe by some mode of reasoning not strictly founded in set theory.

Is my description/interpretation here an accurate characterization of Skolem's views? Also (maybe more importantly), does it describe a view that's at all common among set theorists currently?

Comment: There is a nice discussion at at the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy,  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-skolem/. But since you've already looked at Jané's paper, you've probably also seen it.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss , thanks for the link. It seems there are adherents to this “Skolemite” view, i.e. that the only fully legitimate models are “externally countable” ones (models which one way or another are countable when viewed “from the outside”). But is it a prevalent view, or is it a small minority (even “fringe”) view? That Encyclopedia page suggests that Joel Hamkins’ multiverse concept implies that every set (if not every *model*) is “externally countable”, but is that accurate? The referenced papers by Hamkins don’t *explicitly* make that claim.

Comment: You’ll probably want to read his multiverse paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4223.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss : Ah, on pg. 25 I see the assertion that every universe $V$ is actually countable in some “better” universe $W$. But the discussion of non-standard arithmetic in section 5 makes me wonder if this “countability” of $V$ may in some cases be defined in relation to a non-standard $\omega$ that is itself “absolutely uncountable” (i.e. not in any way bijectable with ***standard*** $\mathbb{N}$). Is Hamkins’ concept in fact the same as the “Skolemite” view that for every model $M$ there is, in some way, a 1-1 correspondence between the sets of $M$ and ***standard*** $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: *(I realize the answer might be obvious to readers well-versed in forcing, but it’s not obvious to me…)*

Comment: Hamkins, as I understand it, doesn't believe that the phrase "the standard $\mathbb{N}$" has a clear meaning. You might enjoy reading this blog thread: https://diagonalargument.com/mathnotes/nonstandard-models-of-arithmetic-the-series/. (The second entry in particular.)

Comment: The forcing argument uses the technique of "collapsing cardinals". The details and the "meaning" of this, as it applies to the multiverse concept, are too long for a comment.